# How to cleanly update a list of HABTM associations in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many, strong-parameters

I'm trying to update a `User` record with the list of associated `Addresses`, connected through the **has and belongs to many association**.

The request body I'm sending through **javascript** is:

```
{"id":10,"name":"John Smith", "address_ids":[4,8]}
```

This is what I'm getting in the Rails **server log**:

> Started PUT "/api/users/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-03 16:30:43 +0200
>
> Processing by Api::UsersController#update as HTML
>
> Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"10", "name"=>"John Smith", "address_ids"=>[4, 8],
>   "user"=>{"id"=>"10", "name"=>"John Smith"}}

The thing to notice above is the `address_ids` array is not making it into the `user` hash according to the log.

In the **controller** i'm using **strong parameters** and updating the `User` like so:

```
attributes = params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, {:address_ids => []}) 
@user.update_attributes(attributes)
```

The problem is the attributes don't contain the address_ids at the point of update so the associated records are not getting updated.

### Temporary Solution

I've worked around the issue manually assigning the `address_ids` key to the `attributes` after they come back from the strong parameters check like so:

```
attributes = params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, {:address_ids => []})
if params.has_key?(:address_ids)   
  attributes[:address_ids] = params[:address_ids] 
end
@user.update_attributes(attributes)
```

This works fine but doesn't seem to me this is how it is supposed to work?
Why are the `adderss_ids` not getting auto assigned? How can this be implemented in a clear way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the addresses saved with the User you need to ensure your client side code sends the `address_ids` parameters as follows:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"id"=>"10", "name"=>"John Smith", "address_ids"=>["4", "8"]}}
```

The input field `name` attribute will be something like:

```
<input name="user[address_ids][]">
```

I also noticed you seem to have your user attributes repeated in your parameters so you may want to carefully review how your client code is generating the request.

Comment: Thanks. To sum up, the solution is to make sure the object sent from javascript has the root key with the name of the resource. Still not clear why some of the fields get assigned correctly even without it and some not...

Comment: Is there any way  to do this by passing `Address` UUIDs rather than expose the sequential IDs?

Comment: @John. I'm definitely in favor of UUIDs for a whole lot of reasons, but in this case whether the ids are UUIDs or sequential integers doesn't make a difference to the approach here. Whatever IDs are passed, they come from the database regardless of the ID scheme used.